# ¿Cómo centrar una tabla con respecto al ancho del documento?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf, reportlab

Estoy usando `reportlab==3.2.0` y quiero saber la forma de poder centrar el `Table` de `platypus`. Tengo lo siguiente dentro de una función AJAX en Django:

```
# Response
response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="somefilename.pdf"'
# Crear PDF
pdf = SimpleDocTemplate(
    response,
    pagesize=A4,
    rightMargin=inch/2,
    leftMargin=inch/2,
    topMargin=inch,
    bottomMargin=inch/2
)
Story = []
# Estilos
styles = getSampleStyleSheet()
styles.add(ParagraphStyle(name='Center', alignment=TA_CENTER))
# Cabecera
text = '''
    <strong><font size=14>REPORTE DE ASISTENCIA</font></strong>
'''
Story.append(Paragraph(text, styles['Center']))
Story.append(Spacer(1, 15))
data = [(
    Paragraph('<strong><font size=6>#</font></strong>', styles['Center']),
    Paragraph('<strong><font size=6>DNI</font></strong>', styles['Center']),
    Paragraph('<strong><font size=6>APELLIDO PATERNO</font></strong>', styles['Center']),
    Paragraph('<strong><font size=6>APELLIDO MATERNO</font></strong>', styles['Center']),
    Paragraph('<strong><font size=6>NOMBRES</font></strong>', styles['Center']),
    Paragraph('<strong><font size=6>JORNADA</font></strong>', styles['Center']),
    Paragraph('<strong><font size=6>HORA DE INGRESO</font></strong>', styles['Center']),
    Paragraph('<strong><font size=6>HORA DE SALIDA</font></strong>', styles['Center']),
)]
# Registros
for counter, record in enumerate(records, 1):
    nro_documento = record['nro_documento']
    apellido_paterno = record['apellido_paterno']
    apellido_materno = record['apellido_materno']
    nombres = record['nombres']
    jornada = record['fecha'].strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
    fecha_hora_entrada = ''
    fecha_hora_salida = ''
    if record['fecha_hora_entrada']:
        fecha_hora_entrada = record['fecha_hora_entrada'].strftime('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')
    if record['fecha_hora_salida']:
        fecha_hora_salida = record['fecha_hora_salida'].strftime('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')
    data.append((
        Paragraph('<font size=6>%s</font>' % counter, styles['Normal']),
        Paragraph('<font size=6>%s</font>' % nro_documento, styles['Normal']),
        Paragraph('<font size=6>%s</font>' % apellido_paterno, styles['Normal']),
        Paragraph('<font size=6>%s</font>' % apellido_materno, styles['Normal']),
        Paragraph('<font size=6>%s</font>' % nombres, styles['Normal']),
        Paragraph('<font size=6>%s</font>' % jornada, styles['Normal']),
        Paragraph('<font size=6>%s</font>' % fecha_hora_entrada, styles['Normal']),
        Paragraph('<font size=6>%s</font>' % fecha_hora_salida, styles['Normal'])
    ))
table = Table(
    data,
    colWidths=50 # Valor del ancho de las columnas
)
table.setStyle(
    TableStyle([
        ('VALIGN',(0, 0), (-1, -1),'MIDDLE'),
        ('INNERGRID', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 0.25, colors.black),
        ('BOX', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 0.25, colors.black),
    ])
)
Story.append(table)
pdf.build(Story)
```

Como pueden apreciar estoy usando un ancho estático de `50` ya que no encuentro la manera de centrar la tabla, la idea es que este ancho varíe por el tipo de columna. Asi es como se ve mi PDF, hay demasiado espacio libre en los bordes izquierdo y derecho y si aumento el ancho de la columna entonces excede el ancho del documento:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Gracias a @AntonioBeamud pude llegar a mi respuesta definitiva, no tenía idea de que se podía pasar una lista en la definición de `Table`. Esta es la solución más óptima según mi parecer aunque estoy abierto a soluciones más eficientes.

En `reporlab` el valor para `inch` (pulgada) es de `72.0`:

```
>>> from reportlab.lib.units import inch
>>> inch
72.0
```

Los márgenes que estoy usando son los siguientes:

```
pdf = SimpleDocTemplate(
    response,
    pagesize=A4,
    rightMargin=inch/2,
    leftMargin=inch/2,
    topMargin=inch,
    bottomMargin=inch/2
)
```

Con lo que tenemos en el margen izquierdo y derecho un valor de `36.0` (`inch/2`):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora, el tamaño del papel en formato A4 según la siguiente tabla es de 8.3 x 11.7 (pulgadas):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces, mediante un simple cálculo podemos determinar el ancho total de nuestro papel y el espacio total restante con respecto a los márgenes:

```
>>> from reportlab.lib.units import inch
>>> ancho = inch * 8.3
>>> ancho
597.6
```

El espacio total de los márgenes izquierdo y derecho es de `72.0` (`inch / 2 * 2`). Con lo que tendríamos para el espacio total:

```
>>> ancho -= (inch / 2 * 2)
>>> ancho
525.6
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aun asi, calcular el total del ancho de cada columna es un tema más de prueba y error que de otra cosa. Por lo que probando llegue al siguiente resultado final para mis columnas:

```
table = Table(
    data,
    colWidths=(30, 40, 90, 90, 90, 45, 70.3, 70.3)
)
```

La suma de las columnas:

```
>>> 30 + 40 + 90 + 90 + 90 + 45 + 70.3 + 70.3
525.6
```

El resultado es una tabla que aprovecha perfectamente el espacio del ancho total con respecto a los márgenes:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero les sirva a otros para futuras referencias y evitar dolores de cabeza.

### Referencias:

- [Dimensions Of A Series Paper Sizes](http://www.papersizes.org/a-paper-sizes-tsta.htm?utm_expid=76296969-982.kASdVbYdSVa5OPFbYmJy5A.1&utm_referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com.pe%2F)

Answer (score 6):

En tu caso, si no especificas el ancho de las columnas, te lo calculará dinámicamente y creo que tampoco se ajustará al resultado que esperas. Yo creo que lo mejor sería especificar el ancho que quieres por columna, creo que algo así te debe funcionar:

```
table = Table(
    data,
    colWidths=[20,40,40,40,40,30,60,60]
)
```

(O bueno, los ajustes que necesites)

Comment: Antonio, gracias! Tu respuesta me ha ayudado bastante y me ayudó a llegar a la solución definitiva la cual presentare en unos minutos. Incluso con tu respuesta, no se puede decir que la tabla este centrada con respecto a los bordes definidos de la página